# Year-over-Year Quicksight Line Chart

Tags: data-visualization, amazon-quicksight

I am looking for a way to do a year-over-year line chart for comparing values at the same time frame (day/week/month) compared to the previous year. When looking for examples I am seeing a lot of line charts with an x-axis with values looking like "MM YYYY". What I am trying to do is to create a chart with an x-axis with values looking like "MM" and then different colored lines representing those values at a different year.  Below is an example from Tableau...I am wondering if I can create something like this in Quicksight

[YoY Tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCSbJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can.
Pick a line chart on the visualize panel and
on the fields well add the year in the color
[image]

The result will be something like this

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution.  Though, one thing I was hoping for was to keep my x-axis as a date value rather than simply the month integer.  The scroll bar on the x-axis is very nice to use with dates because it zooms between the month/week/day levels.  Is there a way to do this while keeping the x-axis as a date value?

Comment: Yes with a date field in the x axis  and you can choose to format it as you like. Just I had a month integer field handy in order to show you how to do it.

Comment: @johnzarifis Do you mind sharing more information about how your fields are designed? Maybe show a table representation of the same visual.

Answer (score 0):

Reply To: Ivar Eriksson
Was able to get the YoY plot by adding calculated fields for Month=substring(toString(),6,2)
Year=substring(toString(),0,5)

Reply To:
There is a hack suggested to the X-Axis in DateFormat rather than the integer month. Please refer
https://repost.aws/questions/QUuKTyrb-5RWaZ1diIBSlj4g/how-to-make-a-year-over-year-line-chart-in-quick-sight

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).