# Quicksight - Making a Year-over-Year Plot

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am trying to make a year-over-year line chart in QuickSight just like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68745441/year-over-year-quicksight-line-chart) post. I have (to my knowledge) done the same thing but I have an issue with my chart not "wrapping", see picture below. The week number comes out right as you can see at the right of the x-axis but the x-axis itself doesn't go from 1-52 but rather from 23-52-1-3. I am very new to QuickSight so I don't really understand why this is happening or how to remedy it, do you?

The appropriate field wells look like below and the date variables are made from a "regular" date with  the built in `truncDate` to extract the week numbers. The original post doesn't explain the structure of their field wells unfortunately.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a new field called `WEEK_NUMBER` as follows:

```
  dateDiff(
    truncDate('YYYY', {otd_event_date}), 
    {otd_event_date},
    'WK'
  )
```

Then use this new `WEEK_NUMBER` field in the x axis field well.

Comment: We came up with an alternative solution that added the week number in the original table but this would probably work as well. Thanks!